# how to add .lib file generated by Keil MDK to GCC project

Tags: makefile, arm, lib

I have a library mylib.lib created using Keil MDK. I have a GCC project (STM Cube) where I need to use this library. It seems to me it wants libmylib.a file. Could you please let me know how to do so.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
..ARMCC\bin\fromelf.exe --elf mylib.lib --output mylib.elf
```

2. 

Add `mylib.elf` to the library list used in the gcc based project.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen,
I'll try to follow your advice ASAP and let you know.

Comment: My attempt failed.
I did follow #1. No problem there. The problem is that then I need to include my library to a project made with STM Cube.  GCC library  .a  builds fine. Cube doesn't see .elf. The same if I change extension to .a...  Description: cannot find -lmy_lib

Comment: Add the elf file not as a library but as an additional object file.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do so using STM Cube? Do I need just manually change .ld file or GUI allows doing that?  Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681360/gcc-can-compile-with-object-file-compiled-from-keil-arm-compiler

Comment: Open Project properties, there: 
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MCU GCC Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Additional Object Files -> Add (the file(s), converted by FROMELF.EXE from .LIB or .O in KEIL-Format).

Comment: As I described above, I need to add mylib to the CUBE project. I don't see any list of obj files within given ld file. Files with the extension .a(or maybe .lib but only one of them) are just added to the such project.   Cube doesn't take .elf. Changing the extension did not help.

Comment: 1. LD file is a linker script file. TyPo? 2. I have no idea, what does not work in your system. I can just repeat: 2.1. convert *.LIB files created under KEIL to *.elf by FROMELF as I wrote before. 2.2. Add those converted files to the list of the additional object files in project settings as I also wrote before. 2.3. Pay special attention, to what configuration - debug or release - you add the files: may be you add them to release but compile debug and have error messages.